# Moodle's usernames lowercase only

Tags: moodle, lowercase

Currently Moodle doesn't allow letters other than lowercase as username. Is there a way to change this rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its because Moodle can be used with several types of databases - some databases ignore the case which is okay but some don't ignore the case - which would be confusing if 2 users had the same username but with different caps.

There might also be checks in the code where case sensitivity is important.

I wouldn't recommend it but if you really want to use uppercase usernames then search for the string id 'usernamelowercase' and remove the checks - in Moodle 2.5 these are in:

/auth/emailadmin/signup_form.php - in the validation function

/login/signup_form.php - in the validation function

/user/editadvanced_form.php - in the validation function

/user/lib.php - 2 functions for adding and updating a user

Comment: Keep in mind that manually editing the source code means that with every update you'll have to reinstate the changes manually.